# How to escape html generate by a loop

Tags: theme-development, code, sanitization, escaping, theme-review

I have the following code which is flagging a warning that I've been asked to fix by my theme reviewer.

```
WARNING All output should be run through an escaping function (see the Security sections in the WordPress Developer Handbooks), found '$fontListStr'.
```

The $fontListStr in the warning message refers to the final line of the following code:

```
              foreach( $this->fontList as $key => $value ) {
            $fontCounter++;
            $fontListStr .= '<option value="' . esc_attr($value->family) . '" ' . selected( $this->fontValues->font, $value->family, false ) . '>' . esc_html($value->family) . '</option>';
            if ( $this->fontValues->font === $value->family ) {
              $isFontInList = true;
            }
            if ( is_int( $this->fontCount ) && $fontCounter === $this->fontCount ) {
              break;
            }
          }
          if ( !$isFontInList && $this->fontListIndex ) {
            // If the default or saved font value isn't in the list of displayed fonts, add it to the top of the list as the default font
            $fontListStr = '<option value="' . esc_attr($this->fontList[$this->fontListIndex]->family) . '" ' . selected( $this->fontValues->font, $this->fontList[$this->fontListIndex]->family, false ) . '>' . esc_html($this->fontList[$this->fontListIndex]->family) . ' (default)</option>' . $fontListStr;
          }
          // Display our list of font options
          echo $fontListStr;
```

I can't for the life of me work out how to escape the final line of code without breaking the output. I actually don't understand why I need to either as I escape all potential vulnerabilities in the lines before.

Could you please help me escape this properly.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have done the trick:

```
  // Display our list of font options
          $allowed_html = array(
              'option' => array(
                  'value' => array(),
                  'selected' => array()
              ),
          );
          echo wp_kses($fontListStr, $allowed_html);
```